# Export Key Value in Redis Desktop Manager

Tags: database, hash, redis

I created some hashes by using Redis Destop Manager and in another computer my teammate created some othersçWe tried to export mine by using Manage Connection button but the .xml file that was created by redis desktop managaer didnt launch in my teammates computer.I checked redis installation directory but even there I couldnt find the hashes.

Comment: Which version of Redis are you using? What is the task you want to accomplish? I ask these questions because I think by using Redis Desktop Manager you are dealing with a faulty mental model of how Redis works.

Comment: Version: redis-desktop-manager-0.7.6.15
WE want to create datamodel with hashes but we are working individualy so I trying to copy the hashes that I created to his computer

Comment: That's a GUI for accessing Redis, not Redis itself. And my guess is that by using that GUI you are not getting at the core concepts of Redis. I say that because trying to "find the hashes" looks like a very suspicious goal. Do you have the redis-cli tool installed?

Comment: yes i have redis-cli tool